# Scrollview in Storyboard ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

As shown in the above picture, I am trying to create a scrollview in storyboard. everything works well and when I run the app, i can scroll through the view.

Problem is, during the storyboard design phase, i am unable to scroll down the view to the below part of the scroll view? any idea how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can not scroll from the storyboard, for design purpose do following

From storyboard

1. select your VC

[image]

2. From Right panel select freedom size

[image]

3. Now select your VC size

[image]

**NOTE:** when your design is completed make sure now your VC is in fixed mode.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to enlarge that controller by:

1. **Selecting** the viewcontroller

[image]

2. **Changing** the simulated size:

[image]

Once all the editing it done you can set the simulated size back to **Fixed**

In this way you are able to see the whole screen at once while designing the UI

Answer (score 0):

Tap on the view, go the the attribute inspector and then change the y position to something negative, say -100,
Do your UI changes accordingly and then again put the y value as 0.

Note : During the time you change it to negative, constraints are going to be orange, signifying that they are not correct. But once you put them back to 0, they are going to be fine.